# Writing to a plist containing an Array of Dictionaries

Tags: ios, dictionary, plist

I am attempting to write to a plist containing an array of dictionaries. Each dictionary contains a string that defines an attribute of that dictionary (room). I only want to write to one String to set that attribute to something based on the result of an if statement.

An example of the plist:

> Rooms =     (

```
        {
       Availability = unavailable;
        Floor = 1;
        Name = "Ferret Room";
        Status = Busy;
        Time = "4.00pm";
    },
            {
        Availability = unavailable;
        Floor = 1;
        Name = "Squirrel Room ";
        Status = Busy;
        Time = "4.00pm";
    },
```

And here is the example of my code:

```
        NSString* newPlistPath = nil;
    NSFileManager* manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ((newPlistPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Favourites/Favourites.plist"]))
    {
        if ([manager isWritableFileAtPath:plistPath])
        {
            NSMutableDictionary* infoDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
            NSLog(@"infoDict %@", infoDict);
            NSLog(@"infoDict %@", [[infoDict objectForKey:@"Availability"] objectAtIndex:0]);

            [infoDict setValue:@"available" forKey:@"Rooms.Availability"];
            [infoDict writeToFile:newPlistPath atomically:NO];
            [manager setAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSDate date] forKey:NSFileModificationDate] ofItemAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] error:nil];
        }
    }
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. There are similar questions but with no solution to what I'm trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: You can't write to the app bundle, it's read-only.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Make a path to the plist in the Documents directory (not the bundle directory, because you can't write to that directory)
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString * newPlistPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Favourites.plist"];

NSFileManager* manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ((newPlistPath)
{
    if ([manager isWritableFileAtPath:plistPath])
    {
        NSMutableDictionary* infoDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
        NSLog(@"infoDict %@", infoDict);
        NSLog(@"infoDict %@", [[infoDict objectForKey:@"Availability"] objectAtIndex:0]);

        [infoDict setValue:@"available" forKey:@"Rooms.Availability"];
        [infoDict writeToFile:newPlistPath atomically:NO];
        [manager setAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSDate date] forKey:NSFileModificationDate] ofItemAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] error:nil];
    }
}
```